# Can anyone solve this integral?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I want to know what is the integral of $$y=\frac{\exp(a+bx+cx^2)}{1+\exp(a+bx+cx^2)}.$$

Thanks so much. I can remember how to integrate.

Comment: No one knows how to make it?

Comment: a,b, and c are constants?

Answer (score -2):

Assume $c\neq0$ for the key case:

\begin{align}
\int \frac {e^{a+bx+cx^2}} {1+e^{a+bx+cx^2}} \,\Bbb dx
&= \int \frac 1 {e^{-a-bx-cx^2}+1} \,\Bbb dx \\
&= \int \frac 1 {e^{-c\left(x^2+\frac{bx}{c}+\frac{a}{c}\right)}+1} \,\Bbb dx \\
&= \int \frac 1 {e^{-c\left(x^2+\frac{bx}{c}+\frac{b^2}{4c^2}+\frac{a}{c}-\frac{b^2}{4c^2}\right)}+1} \,\Bbb dx \\
&= \int \frac 1 {e^{-c\left(\left(x+\frac{b}{2c}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4c^2}\right)}+1} \,\Bbb dx \\
&= \int \frac 1 {e^\frac{b^2-4ac}{4c}e^{-c\left(x+\frac{b}{2c}\right)^2}+1} \,\Bbb dx \\
\left(\text{Let }u=x+\frac{b}{2c}\right) \\
&= \int \frac 1 {e^\frac{b^2-4ac}{4c}e^{-cu^2}+1} \,\Bbb du \\ 
(\text{Let }v=u^2) \\
&= \int \frac 1 {2\sqrt{v}\left(e^\frac{b^2-4ac}{4c}e^{-cv}+1\right)} \,\Bbb dv
\end{align}

Which may relate to the [incomplete polylogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_polylogarithm).